# Parameter Scanner

Tags: java, methods, parameters, java.util.scanner

this is my problem:

I have a method where one of the parameter is a Scanner cons, something like this:

```
public void buyIngredients (Scanner cons){}
```

and it's works, but the error is in the main:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main{

public static void main(String [] args){
Hero h = new Hero();
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int value = scan.nextInt();
System.out.println(h.buyIngredients(value));
```

And the error is this:

```
Main.java:11: error: method buyIngredients in class Hero cannot be applied to given types;
System.out.println(h.buyIngredients(value)); 
                    ^
 required: Scanner
 found: int
 reason: actual argument int cannot be converted to Scanner by method invocation conversion
```

Comment: The error says exactly what is wrong. It wants a `Scanner`, and you're providing an `int`. Please read the error text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `buyIngredients (Scanner cons)` takes a `Scanner` object in.  In your code you are passing in `value`, which is an `int`.  You can't type cast an `int` to a specific object.

Comment: I think a must be more specific, but how i fix it?

Comment: Pass in a `Scanner` object. You created one two lines before the error! `Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);`

Comment: @Leigh even when a `Scanner` is passed, that function returns `void`.  This is just a slew of problems all stuck together.

Comment: @Walls - Very true. I was just starting with the first error ie Fix the errors one at a time and go from there ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Your method `buyIngredients` takes a `Scanner` but you have passed an `int`, which is incorrect.  Pass the `Scanner` instead:

```
System.out.println(h.buyIngredients(scan));
```

Comment: i try it whit scan, and the error is now: 'void' type not allowed here
 System.out.println(h.CompraIngredientes(scan)); 
And mark scan

Comment: @Fletcher your issue is that you are trying to pass the wrong variable types into these functions.  Whatever you define in the `()` for the function, is the type of object the code is expecting.  If you provide a different type, the function won't know what to do, and throw these errors you are seeing.

Comment: Your method `buyIngredients` doesn't return anything; the method signature says `void`.  What are you attempting to print?

Comment: @rgettman yes, it's void and doesn't return nothing, i try to print a menu, just calling that method

Comment: @Walls so for fix it, i need to pass a variable of type Scanner?

Comment: @Fletcher going back to what @rgettman is saying, `buyIngredients` is a void and doesn't return anything.  The code won't know what to print when you call that function inside the `system.out.print`.  Think about what you are trying to print, and then looking at what functions you have returning that type of data.

Comment: @Fletcher, Call `h.buyIngredients(scan)` outside of `System.out.println`.  Your comment above is the first appearance of a "menu".  Not knowing what that is, your code may look something like this: `System.out.println(h.getMenu());`.

Comment: @Walls thanks for the help, I quit the part of System.out.println and it's works, and print a "menu" of ingredients to buy, one more time thanks and a apology for my bad english

Comment: @rgettman thanks for the help, I quit the part of System.out.println and it's works, and print a "menu" of ingredients to buy, one more time thanks and a apology for my bad english

Answer (score 1):

Your `buyIngredients(Scanner cons)` method wants a Scanner as the parameter. I suspect it should be changed to `buyIngredients(int cons)`, but there is no way for me to know unless I can see the method body.